# Configuring IntelliJ IDEA 2016 so that the braces of object literals in Typescript are on a new line but not indented

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, code-formatting, intellij-16

Right now, when I format the following code,

```
let a = {
    x: true,
    y: false,
    z: true
};

let b = 
{
    x: true,
    y: false,
    z: true
};
```

I get this result:

```
let a = {
    x: true,
    y: false,
    z: true
};

let b =
    {
        x: true,
        y: false,
        z: true
    };
```

My goal is to get this as output:

```
let a =
{
    x: true,
    y: false,
    z: true
};

let b =
{
    x: true,
    y: false,
    z: true
};
```

Alternatively, I'd settle for having `a` unchanged and having `b` maintaining its indentation.

```
let b =
{
    x: true,
    y: false,
    z: true
};
```

We could solve this by using formatter on and off tags, but then the content of the object literal (such as callback functions and arrays) wouldn't get formatted anymore, so this is not a preferable solution.

These are the current formatting settings for "Wrapping and Braces":
[image: Wrapping and braces tab of the formatting settings for TypeScript]

If there's a solution which only works in IntelliJ 2017 then that might be workable too, since we're looking into upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `Braces placement/Other` does not affect object literals, so there is no way to make them formatted this way. Please follow [WEB-7122](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7122) for updates